# SSIS - Pulling data from sql view

Tags: ssis

I am creating a SSIS package to pull data using a SQL View. I have three views to pull the data from. The result from each view would be treated as a separate recordset. I am creating a dataflow to achieve this. I basically have to loop through the recordsets and call webservice to pass one row of data at a time.What is the best possible way to do this ? Do I need to create three data flow tasks or can it be achieved in single dataflow task. I think I dont need to store the data that is retrieved from the view. But what is the way in reading and passing the data in SSIS.

Comment: Why are you calling a web service for this?

Comment: I am using a webservice because thats the only mechanism for me to upload data on our client site. They have provided us a Upload webservice which we can use
to upload the data. The only drawback of this service is that it accepts one row of data at a time which would be delimited string which would contain field
values.

Comment: You can accomodate 3 (sql view --> recordset) inside a single DFT. Calling web service is something you would need to do in a `Web Service Task` in Control Flow, NOT the data flow.

Comment: My query is how do i loop through each recordset and call the webservice. I am planning to do the webservice call using the script task. For e.g I get three recordsets. I loop through the first recordset and call the webservice via script task. Then loop through the second recordset and all the webservice via script task. So on and so forth

Comment: That's what I said. Script task/Web Service task is something that needs to be dealt with in the Control Flow, not data flow. The 3 recordsets you need can be populated in a single DFT. Once there, upload the data from the recordsets in the script taks/Web Service Task.

Comment: If it's the latter, use a sequence container.

Comment: Do not bring unrelated data into a data flow. Put it into separate tasks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do what you describe in your last comment is to use an Execute SQL task to query your view and populate an object variable.   Then use your script task to iterate through the rows in the variable (cast the object variable as a DataTable) and call your web service.

You can put this process inside a Loop Container, if the script will be exactly the same for all three views.  Otherwise I would use three separate sets of Execute SQL / Script Task.